# How to Highlight a single bar on click in amcharts v4

Tags: amcharts

I have a column chart from amcharts. I need to highlight a single bar on click on bar. Current scenario is when I click multiple bar, all bars highlighted.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKpa9.png)

```
var highState = series.columns.template.states.create("highlight");
    highState.properties.fill = am4core.color("#8c8c8c");

var highState = series.columns.template.states.create("default");
highState.properties.fill = am4core.color("#333333");

     var activeState = series.columns.template.states.create("active");
activeState.properties.fill = am4core.color("#E94F37");

series.columns.template.events.on("hit", function(ev) {

    for (var j = 0; j < !ev.target.isActive.length; ++j) {
    if (ev.target.isActive) { 

      series.columns.template.setState("default");
        ev.target.setState("default");
        ev.target.isActive = !ev.target.isActive;
    }
   else {
     State = undefined;
      !series.columns.template.setState("active");
        ev.target.isActive = !ev.target.isActive;
         series.columns.template.setState("highlight");         ev.target.isActive;
    State = ev.target.isActive;
   }



    }


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To highlight a single column on click, first make the columns toggleable:

```js
series.columns.template.togglable = true;
```

Now, when you click a column, it will toggle between its active and default states along, so you just need to create the active state and define its properties. You're already doing that with these 2 lines of code:

```js
var activeState = series.columns.template.states.create("active");
activeState.properties.fill = am4core.color("#E94F37");
```

And that's it! No need for hit events and the like.

If you want it so that only one column is ever highlighted at a time, then we do need a hit event, we'll just reset every column except the one that was clicked (whether they were active or not is irrelevant). The `series.columns` is a [list template](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/list-templates/), so it has an `each` method that allows us to iterate over all the actual columns (a lot like `Array.forEach`):

```js
series.columns.template.events.on("hit", function(event) {
  series.columns.each(function(column) {
    if (column !== event.target) {
      column.setState("default");
      column.isActive = false;
    }
  })
});
```

Here's a demo:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/abd6da81e3bd7004f70eb6069a135219

Comment: how to toggle column by index? (lets say #1 or #5) or to toggle column by value?