# How to highlight a column programmatically in AMCharts 4?

Tags: amcharts4

In AMCharts version 3, there is a [demo](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/highlight-column-highest-value/) showing how to highlight a particular column.

Is this possible using AMCharts version 4? For example, in the [Simple Column demo](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/simple-column-chart), highlight the UK column based on its value (ie, where `country = 'UK'`).

I tried modifying the example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54358490/906814 but I can't get a handle on the columns in order to assess their values and then apply the active state highlight ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/slead/w8mzv1tx/10/)).

```
// copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/54358490/906814 but not working yet
var activeState = series.columns.template.states.create("active");
activeState.properties.fill = am4core.color("#E94F37");

series.columns.each(function(column) {
  alert("column") // no alert is seen
  column.setState("active");
  column.isActive = true;
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches you can take.

1) Use an [adapter](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/adapters/) on the column's `fill` and `stroke` and check the column value before modifying the color, e.g.

```
series.columns.template.adapter.add('fill', function(fill, target) {  
  if (target.dataItem && target.dataItem.categoryX == "UK") {
    return "#ff0000";
  }
  return fill;
});

series.columns.template.adapter.add('stroke', function(stroke, target) {  
  if (target.dataItem && target.dataItem.categoryX == "UK") {
    return "#ff0000";
  }
  return stroke;
})
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/b0933b23b5a6c261ab039b87da6105aa?editors=0010)

2) Use a [property field](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/#Property_fields) and set the stroke and fill from your data:

```
chart.data = [
  // ...
  {
    "country": "UK",
    "value": 1122,
    "color": "#ff0000"
  },
  // ...
];
// ...
series.columns.template.propertyFields.fill = "color";
series.columns.template.propertyFields.stroke = "color";
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/bfcd4d79305ca79f239405529fa9792d?editors=0010)